# Get output of batch script into the correct subdir with /R flag

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file

I'm currently facing the problem that I need process files in every sub-directory, I'm using a for loop like this one:

```
for /R %%x in (*.dat) do tool.exe -c -f -e "%%x"
```

Now it does process everything but the tool outputs a file and that file always lands in the directory where the batch script got launched in and not in the directory where the original file was located.
I tried a quite a few approaches like using %CD% as the output directory option for the tool but it looks like the tool didn't like that very much and just gave errors.

I'm looking for a general solution as I had this problem with quite a few CLI tools now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `CD` to the directory where the current `.dat` lies before calling `tool.exe`:

```
for /R %%x in (*.dat) do (cd "%%~dpx" & tool.exe -c -f -e "%%x")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 4):

I'm late on this but, complementing Andriy answer, you can streamline the BAT by combining two FOR loops, which might be slightly more efficient, and more clear.

```
for /D /R %%d in (*) do (
  pushd %%d
  for %%x in (*.dat) do tool.exe -c -f -e "%%x"
  popd
)
```

As an added bonus, this version will solve the case when the main loop refers to a different drive (which is not the case on this particular OP question) and has the relative side value of restoring the current directory on each iteration, which might also be of slight importance in case other commands are incorporated in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forfiles` ...

```
forfiles /s /C /m *.dat "cmd /c tools.exe @file"
```

For more information see http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer aswell! I didn't even know this existed. Could help with future problems.
However the answer above was more what I was trying to do.

Comment: It's a pleasure Paul. Thanks for asking the question and for the upvote. I just found out about forfiles 49 minutes ago. :-)